# How to fix overflow hidden not working with border radius and CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, css

I'm targeting mobile browsers for this issue and using [jQuery.transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/).  Outer circle created using overflow:hidden and big border-radius.  Inner box animates using CSS transitions to cover outer box.  During animation, border-radius of the outerbox does NOT render.  See this example...

http://jsfiddle.net/P7Dkz/2/

```
$('#light').transition({
    y: '0rem',
    delay: 1000
}, 1000);
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: so what exactly is your need? I mean what is the expected outcome?

Comment: I expect th inner box to be clipped by the border-radius during animation.  It should look like a circle the entire time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

in jQuery use top instead 'y', like this

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#light').transition({
        top: '0rem',
        delay: 1000
    }, 1000);
});
```

and CSS remove transform and use top property like this

```
#light {
    background-color:#92bcd5;
    top:10rem;
    /*transform: translate(0, 10rem);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10rem); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Here is [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zainabed/P7Dkz/4/)

Comment: Yah, this has poor performance on mobile though (about 9 fps).  That's why I was using translate rather than top.